# How to re-publish a repository that was previously deleted from github?

Tags: github

A couple months back I deleted a repo from github using "danger zone -> delete this repo" from the project control panel on github.com.

Now I would like to put the code back up on github. I am using the github desktop application to push my code to github.

In the github desktop application, github still thinks the old deleted repo is alive on my account ... so I can't push the code a second time.

How can I completely remove the project from github so that I can push my code again?

Answer (score 4):

I have done this by removing the `[remote "origin"]` section from the `.git/config` file for the project and republishing the repository to github.

Answer (score 1):

If a refresh isn't enough for "GitHub for Windows" to correctly list your GitHub repos, the extreme solution would be to "un-install" and re-install that application.

All the data are under C:\Users\YourAccount\Local Settings\Application Data\GitHub, so removing them and re-installing "GitHub for Windows" should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had to log out from the application and log back in and finally the repository was gone.